# Tomcat, Logon denied for Oracle Database 11gR2

Tags: java, oracle, tomcat, jpa, persistence.xml

I am using JPA by connecting TOMCAT deployed webapp to a Oracle Database 11gR2. I am getting the following error.

javax.persistence.PersistenceException: Exception [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.2.v20131113-a7346c6): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
Internal Exception: java.sql.SQLException: ORA-01017: invalid username/password; logon denied

My persistence.xml is

`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd">
    <persistence-unit name="tdoc" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
        <provider>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider</provider>
        <class>mil.osd.dmdc.diss.tdoc.model.AbstractModelObject</class>
        <class>mil.osd.dmdc.diss.tdoc.model.GeneratedFile</class>
        <class>mil.osd.dmdc.diss.tdoc.model.Template</class>
        <class>mil.osd.dmdc.diss.tdoc.model.TemplateFile</class>
        <properties>
            <property name="eclipselink.jdbc.bind-parameters" value="false"/>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver"/>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:oracle:thin:localhost:1521:tdoc"/>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="test"/>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="TEST"/>

            <property name="eclipselink.target-server" value="None"/>
            <property name="eclipselink.logging.level.sql" value="FINE"/>
            <property name="eclipselink.logging.parameters" value="true"/>
        </properties>

    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>`

The credentials I'm providing are definitely right since I can use them to connect to SQL Developer and SQL Plus. PLEASE HELP! I've been stuck on this for hours.

Also I tried turning off Case sensitivity and it doesn't seem to work either.

*EDIT*
I forgot to mention I am also using maven to build the project, it looks like this just in case my dependency for eclipselinks is wrong

```
    `<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>testdata</groupId>
  <artifactId>testdata</artifactId>
  <version>1.0</version>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <name>testdata</name>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
      <artifactId>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa</artifactId>
      <version>2.5.2-M1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
      <artifactId>ojdbc6</artifactId>
      <version>11.2.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.directory.studio</groupId>
      <artifactId>org.apache.commons.io</artifactId>
      <version>2.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.faces</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.13</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
      <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
      <version>2.5</version>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
  <build>
    <finalName>${project.artifactId}</finalName>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.1</version>
        <configuration>
          <source>1.7</source>
          <target>1.7</target>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.3</version>
        <configuration>
          <warSourceDirectory>src/main/webapp</warSourceDirectory>
          <failOnMissingWebXml>true</failOnMissingWebXml>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>`
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your "javax.persistence.jdbc.url" property looks a bit odd to me.

Try "**jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:tdoc**" instead of "jdbc:oracle:thin:localhost:1521:tdoc" (See the missing "@"?)

Comment: I ended up seeing that before I saw your answer but thank you for the correct response nontheless!

Comment: You are welcome. And if my answer was right, it would be nice if you accept it.

Comment: Sorry How do I do that? There's a lot of restrictions making it impossible for me to do anything with 11 reputation haha.